# Highstock - zoom all by function

Tags: button, zooming, highcharts

I am using Highstock. Is there any possibility to execute the zoom to All - button programmatically in Java Script? Or is there any function with the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by catching button event and add state. You should only check index and set appropriate.

http://jsfiddle.net/jGALb/

```
chart.rangeSelector.buttons[4].setState(2);
chart.rangeSelector.clickButton(4,4,true);
```